# Writing string into table within procedure in DB2

Tags: sql, loops, if-statement, insert, db2

I have the following snipplet:

```
SET retcode = SQLCODE;

IF(retcode='0')THEN
    SET SQLCMDINS = 'INSERT INTO RESULTTBL(SQLC, RET) VALUES ( '' '||SQLCMD||' '' , '||retcode||' )';
    PREPARE myStmt2 FROM SQLCMDINS; 
    EXECUTE myStmt2;
ELSE
    SET SQLCMDINS = 'INSERT INTO RESULTTBL(SQLC, RET) VALUES ("'|| SQLCMD ||'", '|| retcode ||')';
    PREPARE myStmt2 FROM SQLCMDINS; 
    EXECUTE myStmt2;
END IF;
```

The problem is that SQLCMD is not written into the table. The retcode is working fine, but I get nothing for the string. The SQLCMD is the sql command that is being processed during that loop.

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Thanks in advance.

TheVagabond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have some double quotes instead of single quotes in the `ELSE` branch.

However, since you're going to use a prepared statement, why not just use the variables directly, instead of trying to build an SQL statement?

```
-- You can perform these 2 statements early in your procedure, no 
-- need to put this right at the time you're going to execute the
-- INSERT statement     
SET SQLCMDINS = 'INSERT INTO RESULTTBL(SQLC, RET) VALUES (?, ?)';
PREPARE myStmt FROM SQLCMDINS; 

<...other SP code...>
SET SQLC = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SYSCAT.TABLES';
<...other SP code...>

SET retcode = SQLCODE;

EXECUTE myStmt USING SQLC, SQLCODE;
```

Comment: For some reason it doesn't insert into the RESULTTBL. Why the Count(*) SQLC is the sql statement that needs to be inserted. Like 'Insert into table(x,y) values (1,2);' something like that.

Comment: Ok I changed the SQLC SET and changed myStmt to myStmt2 and now it works... so thank you a  lot for helping me fix this prob.

Comment: I don't know what your actual queries are, so the `COUNT(*)` query was just an example.  Corrected the mismatch between `myStmt` / `myStmt2`